# Would like to see more ways to help out.

Tags: feature-request

I would really like more ways to be able to give back to the community, i find myself in a position where i contribute little to nothing to the site. There are very few questions i can actually answer and honestly they usually just result in me asking anther 1-3 more questions just so i can understand an interesting question i come across. when i try to help out ( clicking on the review etc there never any option's with anything in it) and very few of my comments are actually useful on other questions.

I would like to see more feature's to be able to help out as an undergrad student ( as i really can't answer much of anything) also is there a way i can donate real money to the site somehow? ( and if so why isn't it in the FAQ section of the website.)

Comment: Tiny suggestion. You can make your posts more helpful by using proper capitalization  and punctuation. This makes it easier for other users to read your posts, which is certainly helpful. ¶ Also, you can use browse unanswered questions by tags, focusing on tags that correspond to the subject you already learned. (For example, if you are taking differential equations now, you may find it easier to answer questions tagged `calculus` or `sequences-and-series`, etc.)

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How to contribute to Stack Overflow besides asking and answering?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17310/how-to-contribute-to-stack-overflow-besides-asking-and-answering) ...

Comment: This is a commercial site, so donating to it would seem a bit strange.